# What is the state of a license when one of the terms is no longer met?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a piece of software that tracks vehicles. Their license to this software determines how many vehicles they can track.

Is there a term to call the license when there are more vehicles registered than allowed by the license? *Expired* doesn’t really work because that seems to indicate a time constraint. Can a license be *exceeded* perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they violated the terms of your license agreement, didn't they? Probably, you should use *violated license*.

Another word, that springs to mind, is *invalid*.

Or you can just say, that your customer exceeded their quota of allowed vehicles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like to use the term in a message to the user. I'm not a native english speaker, but `violated` seems a bit too harsh. I do like `invalid` maybe the term `invalidated` applies here.

Comment: The license being "invalidated" also means that it has been revoked, which may or may not be what you intend. `Exceeded` does seems to me to work better here. Of course, the best approach would probably be to just have the software inform the user when they exceed their allowed number of vehicles that they cannot add any more, and refuse the action entirely. The user would then have a choice of removing some other vehicle from the database, or to get a license that allows more vehicles to be tracked. Either way, the situation (exceeding the license limit) is avoided.